# School project - IMG with pins and onclick events

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

For my school project, my group and I are making a web app for navigation in a certain area in Denmark called "Brandts" and therefore have made a map with hardcoded pins on. So when you click on a pin it opens the desired shop (a pin has an assigned shop).

[image]

My idea was just to make `onclick` for each `div`, but this is where the trouble begins. I can't get any further. HTML and JavaScript linked below.

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  <div class="map">
      <img src="img/map.png" alt="kort over brandts klædefabrik området" />
      <div id="myBtn" class="cuckoosBox"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: You should use [`btn.addEventListener("click",function(){})`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using (this) keyword?

The keyword could probably help you since it will recognize which you are clicking and you can still pass your onclick function after.

should be something like

`(this.btn).onclick = function () {
 Code here
};`

// or

`(this.div).onclick = function( ) {
};`

Check out more about how "this" keyword works here

http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/

Comment: Thank you! I will give a look tomorrow with my group :)

Comment: also this site is probably better for explanations
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: Also it seems I made a mistake and was thinking of jQuery to use for .click events. If you are able to use jQuery that would be the easiest way to do this because "jQuery performs some JavaScript magic that always makes this refer to the DOM element which triggered the event. That is (one of the many) reasons to use a JavaScript framework instead of rolling your own." In javascript the keyword this refers to the current instance of an object in JavaScript.

`$(".toggleButton").click(function() {

   $(this).toggleClass("active");

  $(this).removeClass("highlighted");`